# Is there a way to keep track of schema change in a Hive metastore?

Tags: hive, apache-hive

I'm looking for a possible solution to keep track of all schema changes in a Hive metastore such as create new table, add/remove columns, change column type and etc. I haven't found any so far. Should I just monitor the MySQL db that stores the meta info?